# File upload recording over the HTTPS is not working, Jmeter is not sending the file name on the request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record the test case where I am uploading the files to some server over the https but getting the failure error from the remote server.
Because I found that, the Jmeter is sending the request without file name (request shows 'actual file content, not shown here')

Observed with Ubuntu 14.04 machine

Comment: Use [Blazemeter Chrome recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) to record the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason, this is the know issue with Ubuntu 14.0, for more info check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jakarta-jmeter/+bug/1524887

Same case working fine after setting the 'HTTP Request -> Implementation -> HttpClient3.1"